# Quote not properly terminated in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am learning plsql 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'. So, for a normal query it is passed using it is declared as:

```
query:='SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME';
execute immediate query;
```

But i wanted to pass the cursor value inside the string of query.But I am getting consufe of how to give the inverted comma  in proper way.I tried it like this:

```
declare
query long;
cursor cur is
select a_name from ot.a;
begin
for i in cur
query='select * from ot.city  b where '||i.a_name||'=''kathmandu'';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATW query;
loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.a_name);
end loop;
end;
/
```

But it is giving me error like this:

```
Error at line 1
ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated
```

What is the proper way to give the inverted comma? I know i made mistake in inverted comma but what is the proper way?

Comment: You need **three** single-quotes after `kathmandu`. The first two are converted to a single quote (needed in the text of your SQL query). The third single-quote actually terminates your query (the quoted string that makes up your query).

Comment: can u please demostrate me an example? itsnot still working

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATW query;  ? Is this correct?
It should be 
EXECUTE Immediate query;

Comment: @Randomguy - "not working"? In what way? I assume you are running into a different error now? So, then, you have a different question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need `INTO` clause in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` if it is `SELECT` query.

Second, your `FOR loop` is not correct.
It should be as following (`execute immediate` should be inside the loop)

```
for i in cur
Loop
..
..
End loop
```

For the missing single quotes, use following query:

```
query='select * from ot.city b where '
       || i.a_name 
       || '=''kathmandu''' ; --Only last single quote was missing.
```

Your logic is not at all clear. Why you need to execute the query using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. There is no usage of returned data in the loop.

Please edit the answer or comment if it not what you required.

Cheers!!

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the what the line should look like

```
query='select * from ot.city b where '||i.a_name||'='' || kathmandu || ''';
```

It is just one apostroph is missing in the end of the line

Comment: @Randomguy sorry, I've build a wrong test case on my DB. This should be working

select 'select * from ot.city b where '|| i.a_name ||' =  ''' || kathmandu || '''' from dual

But only if kathmandu is the name of the table. If this is a string value then you should say the following

select 'select * from ot.city b where '|| i.a_name ||' =  ''kathmandu''' from dual

The main idea is 2 apostrophes will add 1 apostrophe in the string

Comment: You added concatenation operator WITHIN a quoted string. The OP's attempt, incorrect as it was, was better than your attempt. Downvoted for that reason.

Answer (score -2):

instead of

```
query='select * from ot.city  b where '||i.a_name||'=''kathmandu'';
```

put this

```
query='select * from ot.city b where ' || i.a_name || '=''kathmandu'';';
```

Comment: The string of a query in `execute immediate` should **not** be terminated with a semicolon (;). Downvoting for this reason, but it would be best if you deleted your answer, as it is 100% wrong.